# Get play count from top songs on Spotify

Tags: web-scraping, spotify

I'd like to track play counts of songs for popular artists. This doesn't appear to be available through the Spotify API, but it's visible either through the desktop app or the web app [here](https://play.spotify.com/artist/5YGY8feqx7naU7z4HrwZM6). Is there a simple way to scrape this data?

[image: Play Counts for Miley]

Answer (score 2):

No, this data isn't exposed in the [public API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api). This feature was added as an [enhancement request](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/70) in the Web API's public issue tracker less than a month ago. Feel free to add support for it by writing about your use case, or by simply putting a *+1*.